# c - compiler, different errors?

Tags: c

i'm running this code on a macbook with xCode, and it runs flawlessly without any errors. However, when I try to compile and run the exact code on a Red Hat Linux server, I get a segmentation fault at line 25. I'm not sure why this is working for one machine, and not the other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Count the number of times the letter appears in the string
int count_letter(char str[], char * ch) 
{
   int i, num = 0;
   for(i=0; i < strlen(str)-1; i++)
      if(str[i] == *ch)
      {


//printf("The character is %c", ch);
     num++;
      }

   return num;
}

//Get the sentence and character to search for from the user
char * get_info(char * ch) 
{
   char *str;
   //int i=0;

   printf("Enter a sentence to search: ");
   while((str[i++]=getchar())!='\n');
   str[i]='\0';
   printf("Enter a character to search for: ");

   *ch=getchar();

   return str;
}

//Get a sentence and character from the user and count the number
//of times the character is found in the sentence.
int main() 
{

   char *sentence;
   char ch;
   int num_letters;

   sentence = get_info(&ch);
   num_letters = count_letter(sentence, &ch);

   printf("%c is found %d times.\n", ch, num_letters);

   return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You've not allocated space for `str` in `get_info()`, using an uninitialized pointer as an array.  This is bad news on any system.

Comment: should be `i < strlen(str)`

Comment: `for(i=0; i < strlen(str)-1; i++)` is extreemly inefficient. Write `int length = strlen(str) - 1; for(i=0; i < length; i++)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *str;
```

You have not allocated any memory for it in `get_info()`.

So first allocate memory for it.like

```
str= (char *)malloc(MAX_LEN*sizeof(char)); //MAX_LEN=define yourself what you want
```

Comment: wow that's kinda weird... thank you so much for the answer. Any idea why it lets me do it on my macbook?

Comment: @user3736620: it "worked" on the macbook because you were lucky (str happended to point to some valid memory).

Comment: @user3736620 It should not work. And also not assume if it worked than will work always.As Michael Walz said that luck by chance it worked for you.